# Data/partition recover from live usb

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, windows-10, data-recovery

I had 2 drives in Windows 10 - C and E. I have created a unallocated space in from E (shrink it) and then booted from Ubuntu 18 live usb. But when trying to install in that unallocated space, Ubuntu was not showing that partition, rather it was showing whole E: drive and unallocated space together as free space. When I login to windows it shows E drive fine but shows free space in Ubuntu installer. It was showing all the drives fine in GParted though.

Then I have created an partiyon for unallocated space via GParted and tried to install again but it was same in installed step. So finally I deleted the new created volume again. Now this step screwed the whole thing, windows denied to boot again and does show any drive when try with another windows live cd. And when I use Ubuntu live usb, it only shows C drive now (in GParted) and no E drive which it was showing earlier.

When I try to go to repair mode and open command prompt it only shows X: drive which has data of C drive. I am blocked now and not sure how can I recover my E drive data now. Is there any way to recover from this X: drive mode and get back windows working or get data from E drive which aways shows free space in Ubuntu. I never deleted any partition from live usb except the one I created from unallocated space and deleted again. Is my data still available in hard drive? Is there any way to recover that?

Comment: If there are very important data, that you must try hard to recover from the drive with Windows, I suggest that you start by getting two drive with exactly the same size or bigger (not one single byte smaller), install gddrescue, learn about it can create a cloned copy, Do the recover job on the cloned copy. This will decrease the risk that you lose data that should be possible to recover (if you make a mistake, you can create a new cloned copy. (The extra drive is where to write the recovered files (and ddrescue logfiles).

Comment: See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) and scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files' -- The answer about `testdisk` is good, what I suggest is what to do before using it. If `testdisk` fails, you can resort to `photorec`, which can recover files from the data stored on the drive even when the partition table and file system is destroyed. But it is a lot of work, and you lose the directory structure and file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not format or do any other things to your hard disk. Otherwise you may not be able to missing partition and repair a corrupted one. You can recover your overwritten partition table using `testdisk`.

open terminal in live USB and follow steps:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

now type and run `testdisk`.

Read this page [TestDisk Step By Step](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and read this carefully before proceed otherwise you will loose all data or brick your hard disk.

Edit:

If in case you feel that you are not able to recover your partition. Still you can recover your important data after the step of "deep search" after pressing desired button to list files you can copy desired folder or whole disk data to another disk/ location.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the partition visible in testdisk and copied my data.